# Which texts mention that satyabhama was incarnation of bhumi Devi?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavata-purana, satyabhama, mahabharata

As per Wikipedia article on [Satyabhama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyabhama):

> Satyabhama is the third consort of the God Krishna, the eighth avatar of the god Vishnu. **Satyabhama is believed to be an avatar of Bhumī Devī**, the Goddess of Earth who is Prakriti form of Mahalakshmi. She aided Krishna in defeating the demon Narakasura.

Wikipedia mentions satyabhama has incarnation of bhumi devi but I haven't found any such reference in scriptures.Please do provide reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact of Satyabhama as an incarnation of Bhumi Devi (the Goddess of Earth) has been mentioned across several scriptures.

In [Brahma Vaivarta Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Vaivarta_Purana), Krishna says that Vasundhara born as Satyabhama

> Sri Krsna said- ........Savitri the mother of the Vedas would be born
> as the daughter of Nagnajit and would be known with the name of Satya.
> **Vasundhara would be born as Satyabhama** and Sarasvati would be born as
> Saivya
>
> [[243, Chapter 6, Sri Krsna-janma-khanda, Brahma Vaivarta Purana]](https://archive.org/stream/357106450BrahmavaivartaPurana2SanskritTextWithEnglishTranslationPdf/357106450-Brahmavaivarta-Purana-2-Sanskrit-text-with-English-translation-pdf#page/n53/mode/2up)

Shri Narada also says the samething in [Garga Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garga_Samhita)

> Shri Narada said: .... The goddess of fortune will take birth as
> Bhishmaka's daughter Rukmini. Lord Shiva's consort will take birth as
> Jambavati. Tulasi will take birth as Satya and **Vasundhara as
> Satyabhama**.
>
> [[37, Chapter 3, Canto 1, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_1.3:_Description_of_the_Lord%27s_Appearance)

Note that Vasundhara is a name used for [Bhumi devi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C5%ABmi).

Comment: Thank you very much.Does any other scripture mentions this ?

Comment: @RishikeshS Please see this https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/59/38-39/

Answer (score 3):

Devi Satyabhama being the incarnation of Bhumi devi is provided in different scriptures including Brahma Vaivarta purana, Garga samhita, Padma Purana,krishnoupanishad, and Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya.
Brahma Vaivarta Purana(6.141-150):

> 141.Lord Sesa, the master of the universes, will go to Devaki’s womb. Then Yogamaya will pull (sankars) Him into Rohini’s womb. For this reason He will be called Sankarsana.

> 142.Ganga will come to the earth in a partial incarnation as Yamuna. Tulasi will appear in a half-incarnation as princess Laksmana.
>
> 143.Saintly Savitri, the mother of the Vedas, will be named Nagnajiti. **Vasundhara will become Satyabhama**. Goddess Sarasvati will become
> Saibya.[2]

- Garga Samhita 1.3:

> Tulasi will take birth as Satya and **Vasundhara as Satyabhama.**

- Padma Puran (Uttara kanda chapter 29):
  Śrī Rudra said:

> The glorious daughter of Satrājit, named Satyā, born with a **portion of the Earth**, was another wife of Kṛṣṇa. The glorious daughter of the Sun, named Kālindī, was his third wife.

- Krishnoupanishad:

> The "mercy" was born as mother Rohini and the “**mother earth ” was born
> as Sathya Bhama.**

- Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya 20.60:

> **“Śrīmati Rukmiṇī-devī and Śrīmati Satyabhāmā devi are Śrī-Śaktis:
> Śrī-Devi and Bhu-Devi (respectively)”.**

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE. Kindly visit [How Does a New User Get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). Have an enriching journey ahead!